# no overloaded function takes 2 arguments(functors)

Tags: c++, templates

I run into a probles while trying to implement custom comparator support for my Heap data structure
Here's how I want it to look like:

```
    template <class T, class Pred = std::less<T>>
    class ConcurrentPriorityQueue {
    private:

        template <class T>
        class Node
        {
        private:
            T data;
            bool operator < (const Node<T>& t) {
            return Pred(data, t.data);
         }
            };
     };
```

And this is a compare functor I want to use:

```
struct comp {
            bool operator () (const std::pair<int, fn_type> &p1,
                const std::pair<int, fn_type> &p2) const{
                return p1.first < p2.first;
            }
        };
```

```
ConcurrentPriorityQueue<std::pair<int, fn_type>, comp> fqueue;
```

Everything looks pretty much right for me, however I get Error

> Error 2   error C2661: 'ThreadPool::comp::comp' : no overloaded function takes 2 arguments    c:\users\usr\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\secondtask\queue.hpp. Could you please help me out with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Pred` refers to a type, not an instance of that type.

---

Currently you are trying to invoke a constructor of type `Pred` when doing `Pred(data, t.data)`, you will first have to create an instance of `Pred` to be able to call a matching `operator() (...)` on it.

The below example creates a temporary instance of type `Pred`, and then calls its `operator()`;

```
        return Pred () (data, t.data); // 1) create a temporary instance of `Pred`
                                       // 2) call its operator() with `data` and `t.data`
```

Comment: Mvsc2013 recognises `(Pred ()) (data, t.data);` as a cast.       However, I got your idea and `Pred ()(data, t.data)` works just fine.